# Permission denied running perl

Tags: perl

perl 5.18.2 was running fine on my Ubuntu 14.04 system until I needed a package from CPAN which did not exist as an Ubuntu package.  I installed it as root and it didn't work but then the installation process seems to have changed permissions of something.  Now, I cannot run Perl as a normal user.

As a normal user, "perl -v" works.  But "perl -V" gives me this:

$ perl -V

```
Can't locate Config.pm:   Permission denied.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

If I run it under sudo, then it works:

$ sudo perl -V

```
...
@INC:
  /etc/perl
  /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2
  /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2
  /usr/lib/perl5
  /usr/share/perl5
  /usr/lib/perl/5.18
  /usr/share/perl/5.18
  /usr/local/lib/site_perl
  .
```

Indeed, Config.pm exists in /usr/lib/perl/5.18 and its permissions are readable by normal users.  So, something has switched to root and I don't know what has.

Has anyone seen this before and know what I should be looking for?  Out of desperation, I even uninstalled perl and reinstalled it back.  Didn't work.  Though something funny...after uninstalling, I still had a /usr/bin/perl executable.  Not sure if that is related...

Any help would be appreciated!

Ray

Comment: From some googling (see [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1080639)) I understand that if one of the directories in the @INC path is inaccessible, the search for Config.pm (or any module) is abandoned. So check whether any of the directories is not readable by "all".

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I did try using Google but I was coming up with page after page from users who didn't "chmod u+x" their Perl scripts.  Maybe I wasn't thinking clearly and was just putting in the wrong keywords into Google.  Anyway, your solution was it.  One of the folders in INC was missing -- that is fine.  But one of the folders in INC had its permissions changed by my module installation.  That was the problem, even though it didn't have a *.pm that I was using.  Please feel free to post a solution that I can accept.  Thank you very much!

Comment: I have non-existent directories in the path myself. Strange that that is no problem. Anyway, good to see your problem solved.

Comment: Yes, the problem was a directory in INC which was owned by root and changed to just root accessible.  I've "sudo" to do a module installation; this is the first time, such a procedure made it unreadable to normal users.  Thank you again for the help!  Indeed, I panicked a bit and didn't think clearly enough to figure out how to Google properly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From some googling (see [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1080639)) I understand that if one of the directories in the @INC path is inaccessible, the search for Config.pm (or any module) is abandoned. So check whether any of the directories is not readable by "all".
Strangely enough, a non-existent directory name in the @INC path is no problem.

Comment: I got the same error when all my INC directories were accessible (or missing), but I had an inaccessible directory in PERLLIB environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can try install `local::lib`. But you'll probably have to reinstall some  Perl modules.

1. `sudo apt-get install cpanminus`
2. `cpanm --local-lib=~/perl5 local::lib eval $(perl -I ~/perl5/lib/perl5/ -Mlocal::lib)`
3. `echo "export PERL5LIB=\"$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5\"">>~/.bashrc && echo "export PERL_MB_OPT=\"--install_base '$HOME/perl5'\">>~/.bashrc && echo "export PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT=$HOME/perl5">>~/.bashrc`

Now, open a new terminal(or run `source ~/.bashrc`) and try to install some Perl module.

Works for me! Hope works for you too! Otherwise, that means your CPAN installation is broken. In this case, use command `sudo dpkg --list | grep libcpan` to list all cpan's packages, try to upgrade packages at first.

If still doesn't work try to remove and reinstall all of them! After that, install `local::lib` again repeating the steps above.

Comment: We do not support private off-site communication (e.g. via email) here, please discuss all question-related topics in comments or in [chat].

Comment: Other than that, do you mean `sudo apt-get install cpanminus` instead?

Comment: Yes, I mean 'sudo apt-get install ...'. Sorry for that!